# xpcomglue_s_nomozalloc.lib is missing from XULRunner SDK 40

Tags: firefox-addon, mozilla, xulrunner

My firefox extension project links with **xpcomglue_s_nomozalloc.lib** and defines **MOZ_NO_MOZALLOC**. But trying to compile it now with XULRunner SDK 40 gives me

```
fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'xpcomglue_s_nomozalloc.lib'
```

All previous versions of the SDK include this file. A link [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1168291) suggests that this is being removed and to use **mozcrt.lib** instead, but that file is not included either.

How can I modify my build to link successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Well for now I just copied xpcomglue_s_nomozalloc.lib and xul.lib from SDK version 39 and it compiles and works. Not ideal, but it's something.